# How to share .apk file from my app using Intent()

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to share .apk file that resides in my app's raw folder using `Intent()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can share using Intent. This should help you.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "File Name");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(
  "android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.apkname));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: This isn't working because sharingIntent.setType can not be set to "text/plain" as its an .apk extension file that i want to share.